# How can I redirect a working copy from a subversion server to a different location?

Tags: svn, version-control, ip-address, local-network

**Direct Question:** With a working copy checked-out from a subversion server, is there a way ??.svn/entries?? to redirect the working copy to a different location from where I originally checked it out?

**Background:** I have a small subversion server which I have visible on the web.  However, living off a cable-modem, my dynamic ip shifts and every so often I have to update the dns entries.  For the next 24 hours, I probably won't be able to sync through the website until my local dns server catches the update.

In the mean time, I'd **really** like to sync -- for the moment -- I'm sitting next to the server and can access it through the local network.  So I tried editing the 'entries' file in the .svn folder, replacing the website name with the local ip address, but it didn't work (I'm not sure why -- it appeared to revert my changes to the entries file & then append file names and version info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `switch` command with `relocate` option.

```
svn switch --relocate https://oldserver/svn/repos https://newserver/some/directory
```

For more information, take a look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html).

You also have that available in TortoiseSVN, under the Relocate context menu.